# The API call doesn't seems working in React

Tags: java, html, css, reactjs, api

I'm building a weather webapp usign React and the [openweathermap.org](https://openweathermap.org/) api.
Until yesterday everything was going in the right direction. Today I resumed writing code but the API call does not produce any results (from how I did in the code below I get an infinite loading). I don't understand where the problem is, also because I haven't changed the code since the last time it worked and I don't get any errors in the console section of the browser.

Here the code:

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import NavBar from '../Components/NavBar/NavBar';
import CurrentData from '../Components/CurrentData/CurrentData';
import HourlyForecast from '../Components/HourlyForecast/HourlyForecast';
import Details from '../Components/Details/Details';
import DailyForecast from '../Components/DailyForecast/DailyForecast';

import 'tachyons';

const App = () => {

  const API_KEY = `my api key`;

  const [searchField, setSearchField] = useState('');
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Cinisi&units=metric&appid=${API_KEY}`)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(dataRecived => setData(dataRecived));
  }, []);

  return !data.length ?
    <h1>Loading...</h1> :
  (
    <React.Fragment>
    <NavBar />
    <CurrentData 
      name={data.name}
      country={data.sys.country}
      temp={data.main.temp}
      time={data.dt}
      desc={data.weather[0].description}
    />
    <HourlyForecast />
    <Details />
    <DailyForecast />
    </React.Fragment>
  );      
}

export default App;
```

I thank anyone who gives me an answer in advance

Comment: First I would try to implement a `catch` method after the `then` in the `useEffect`. Maybe you will get some error code. :)

Comment: First thing I would do would be to try the request on postman, curl or insomnia to see if the problem is not in the request. Did you try to do that?

Comment: are you getting a CORS error or a JS error in your console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE. I found the solution, I setted data hook initially as *null*:

`const [data, setData] = useState(null);`

and the condition to this:

`return !data ....`